# QueryIntentServices doesn't return all needed services

Tags: java, android, service

Here is my project structure:

[image]

"app" and "mylibrary" compiles "platform".

Platform has Application class that is used by "app" in manifest as application class.

In application class I try to get all available services(ServiceDefault from "app" and PluginService from "mylibrary") with this code:

```
public final static String ACTION_PLUGIN_PROVIDER = "12345";

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PLUGIN_PROVIDER);
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

For now all service are empty and only declared. So here is declaration from manifests:

```
<service android:name=".ServiceDefault"><intent-filter><action android:name="12345" /></intent-filter></service>

<service android:name=".PluginService" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote"><intent-filter><action android:name="12345" /></intent-filter></service>
```

My question is in next. Why this line of code returns only resolve info for service placed in "app" called "ServiceDefault."

```
packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

**What I have to change, to get both services(ServiceDefault and PluginService) with resolveIntentServices() method?**